# Rendering Kendo grid Data Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

I need to manipulate end result of some column value in Kendo grid but I did not find any solution like the below example for jquery data tables. Is there any similar way to do it in Kendo grid for angular (some render callback function) because I do not want to change the data during binding because filtration of data depends on it

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: '../ajax/data/objects_salary.txt',
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'name',
        },
        {
            data: 'position',
            render: function (data, type) {
                if (type === 'display') {
                    let link = 'http://datatables.net';

                    if (data[0] < 'H') {
                        link = 'http://cloudtables.com';
                    } else if (data[0] < 'S') {
                        link = 'http://editor.datatables.net';
                    }

                    return '<a href="' + link + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }

                return data;
            },
          });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do it the Angular way by applying the formatting in the component's template.

Here is the relevant documentation on cell templates: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/templates/#toc-cell-template